# how to get selected date from html textbox is-Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was trying to get the differences from two dates..
i was using html is-Date textbox

```
<input type="text" name="datein" id="datein" value="" class="inputtexbox datepicker"   style="display: none" is-Date/> 
<input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto" value="" class="inputtexbox datepicker" style="display: none" is-Date/>


<script>
    alert(document.getElementById("datein").value);
    alert(document.getElementById("dateto").value);
</script>
```

i was trying to get those values to a java script to compare them. but the alert was empty

Comment: the alert will be empty because the values of `datein` and `dateto` is empty.

Comment: add these alert in some kind of event `click` or `change` otherwise they will always be empty. as you haven't entered any value

Answer (score 1):

the alert should call after you typed in the values

the Value is empty -> `value=""`

try this:

```
<input type="text" name="datein" id="datein" value="123" class="inputtexbox datepicker"   style="display: none" is-Date/>
<input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto" value="543" class="inputtexbox datepicker" style="display: none" is-Date/>
<button onclick="alertInputs()">Show Inputs</button>

<script>
    function alertInputs() {
        alert(document.getElementById("datein").value);
        alert(document.getElementById("dateto").value);
    }
</script>
```